# Trying to use std::aligned_storage with SSE and new

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, sse, memory-alignment

I wanted to try getting a square root of some floats using SSE instrincs in C++. But I get a exception when I try to store the result. Can I use std::aligned_storage like that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
using namespace std;

using float_storage = aligned_storage<4 * sizeof(float), 16>;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    float_storage * values = new float_storage[ N / 4 ]; // 4 floats in pack

    for(int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        void *vptr = static_cast<void*>(&values[i]);
        float *fptr = static_cast<float*>(vptr);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            cin >> fptr[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        void *vptr = static_cast<void*>(&values[i]);
        float *fptr = static_cast<float*>(vptr);
        __m128 x = _mm_loadu_ps(fptr);
        x = _mm_sqrt_ps(x);
        _mm_store_ps(fptr, x); // im getting an crash here
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N / 4; i++)
    {
        void *vptr = static_cast<void*>(&values[i]);
        float *fptr = static_cast<float*>(vptr);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            cout << fptr[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] values;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `aligned_storage<size, align>::type`. `aligned_storage` itself is just a metaprogramming struct.

Also, `new` is only rated to `std::max_align_t`, if I recall correctly, even if you `new` up a type with higher alignment requirements.

Comment: But can or cannot?